# Installation of TensorClus Via Pip

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install [the TensorClus library](https://pypi.org/project/TensorClus/). To do so, I do

```
pip install TensorClus
```

When I do this, however, Python complains, saying

> tensorclus depends on numpy 1.18.3, and pandas 1.0.3.

However, when I check to see which versions of these I have via `pip show numpy` and `pip show pandas`, I'm told that I have 1.22.1 `numpy` and `pandas` 1.2.4. I have Python 3.9, and my libraries seem to be up to date. What might the problem be?

EDIT: My coworker found the answer. Apparently the solution was difficult. When he shares it with me tomorrow, I will post the exact solution since it would presumably benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the library is that it [specifies](https://github.com/boutalbi/TensorClus/blob/5201cec6a1f21e96237bf2c4f0fb72f17f0e8ef6/setup.py#L30-L40) the exact versions up to the last component instead of providing reasonable ranges. To install it you need to install these exact versions. The simplest way to do that is to allow `pip` to upgrade/downgrade already installed versions:

```
pip install --upgrade TensorClus
```

Can be shortened to just

```
pip install -U TensorClus
```

PS. And my advice is to always use virtual environments — `virtualenv`, `venv`, `virtualenvwrapper`, `pyenv-virtualenv`, whatever.

Comment: Yes, we tried `pip install -U TensorClus`, and it still doesn't install. We will use the virtual environment, then.

Comment: @JaredGreathouse What was the error in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to downgrade "NumPy" and "Pandas" to the required versions?

pip3 install numpy==1.18.3
pip3 install pandas==1.0.3

Comment: I haven't. Perhaps this is the solution.